# How to webpack vscode-nls

Tags: webpack, vscode-extensions

Webpack throws errors for two of my imports.

The imports look like this.

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as hljs from "highlight.js";
import { readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as http from "http";
import * as child_process from "child_process";
import * as fs from "fs";
import * as portfinder from "portfinder";
import * as nls from 'vscode-nls';
```

The first six are processed without incident, but webpack gets bent out of shape over `portfinder` and `vscode-nls`.

```
> webpack --mode development

Hash: c7d673027a6e241aeb30
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 2503ms
Built at: 11/05/2020 1:23:55 PM
           Asset      Size  Chunks                   Chunk Names
    extension.js  1.23 MiB    main  [emitted]        main
extension.js.map  1.35 MiB    main  [emitted] [dev]  main
Entrypoint main = extension.js extension.js.map
[./src/extension.ts] 15.4 KiB {main} [built] [2 errors]
[child_process] external "child_process" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[fs] external "fs" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[http] external "http" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[net] external "net" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[os] external "os" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[path] external "path" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[tty] external "tty" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[util] external "util" 42 bytes {main} [built]
[vscode] external "vscode" 42 bytes {main} [built]
    + 196 hidden modules

ERROR in D:\_vscode-printing-free\vsc-print\src\extension.ts
./src/extension.ts
[tsl] ERROR in D:\_vscode-printing-free\vsc-print\src\extension.ts(7,29)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'portfinder'.
npm ERR! vscode-print@0.7.17 webpack: `webpack --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
```

Portfinder isn't the real problem; it wouldn't be a big problem to take the code and made an ES6 module out of it, which would probably also stop Typescript from deciding that portNumber is readonly (it should not be).

I did find this on the subject https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/webpack-sample#more

> If you use vscode-nls to localize your extension that you likely also use vscode-nls-dev to create language bundles at build time. To support webpack, a loader has been added to vscode-nls-dev. Add the section below to the modules/rules-configuration.

```js
{
  // vscode-nls-dev loader:
  // * rewrite nls-calls
  loader: 'vscode-nls-dev/lib/webpack-loader',
  options: {
    base: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
}
```

but I've already done what it advises. The most interesting thing about this information is it directly implies that webpack and vscode-nls *can* be used together. Less encouraging, the last few releases of vscode-nls have to do with getting this to work, which suggests it's not entirely straightforward.

Does anyone know of a repo that demonstrates this combination of technologies? A sketch of what is entailed, supported by a reference to a working repo, would be a great help.

Comment: Hi @peter-wone, wondering if you got it to work?

Answer (score 0):

saddly,vscode-nls-dev doesn't support generating and bundling language file (see [that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-nls-dev/blob/main/src/webpack-bundler.ts#L39))

use gulp ,if you want to use budnle language. Or you can expand  [webpack-loader.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-nls-dev/blob/main/src/webpack-loader.ts) and webpack-bundler.ts[enter link description here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-nls-dev/blob/main/src/webpack-bundler.ts)